# How to use basic WCF service stand-alone

Tags: .net, wcf

I have successfully implemented the example in this [How to Host and Run a Basic Windows Communication Foundation Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorial and everything works correctly when running from within Visual Studio.

However, when I go to run the console host app on its own, outside of VS, from the command line - the code acts like everything is working, but there is no http service at the address specified, like when it was running from within VS.

What am I missing here?  Obviously VS is doing something to set up the necessary infrastructure that I'm not seeing - what is that?

EDIT: Code from `Main()`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Step 1 Create a URI to serve as the base address.
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/GettingStarted/");

    // Step 2 Create a ServiceHost instance
    ServiceHost selfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorService), baseAddress);

    try
    {
        // Step 3 Add a service endpoint.
        selfHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new WSHttpBinding(), "CalculatorService");

        // Step 4 Enable metadata exchange.
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        selfHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        // Step 5 Start the service.
        selfHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();

        // Close the ServiceHostBase to shutdown the service.
        selfHost.Close();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An exception occurred: {0}", ce.Message);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        selfHost.Abort();
    }
}
```

My `app.config` from **GettingStartedHost**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

My `App.config` from **GettingStartedLib**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!--<service name="GettingStartedLib.Service1">-->
      <service name="GettingStartedLib.CalculatorService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <!--<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/GettingStartedLib/Service1/"/>-->
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/GettingStarted/CalculatorService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.IService1">-->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/GettingStarted/CalculatorService/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="GettingStartedLib.ICalculator">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. -->
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain code added

Comment: Strange.  Is anything at all listening on port 8080? - could your previous test be keeping this port open?   Are you running from exactly the same file location?  Have you tried with elevated permissions?

Comment: @BenJackson nothing else using port 8080; checked with ``netstat``. Using the exact same ``exe``.VS and ``cmd`` both running as Administrator.

Comment: One other data point: when I run the Host app thru VS, a "WCF Service Host" icon appears in the System Tray. When I start via the command line, it does not appear.

Comment: Can you see if you have "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the solution" checked under WCF Options for either of your projects?  I have just successfully built and run this sample as a single EXE (i.e. Main logic plus the calculator interface / class all compiled in a single EXE assembly) and it works as expected either from the debugger or command-line.

Comment: @BenJackson yes that option is checked in my ``GettingStartedLib`` project. (I am using VS 2013 Premium on W7 x64). Did you create a console app project + WCF Service Lib project, as in the example, or did you create a single WCF Service Application project?

Comment: I just created a single Console application and added a reference to System.ServiceModel.  Can you try unchecking that option? - that should at least make the behaviour consistent between running via VS or command-line.

Comment: @BenJackson if I uncheck that box, I get the same results as running from the command line. If I then run the sample code "Client" project, I get a ``System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException``

Comment: @BenJackson What version .NET fw are you using? (I have tried 4 thru 4.6.1.) Also, I have added the contents of my ``app.config`` files. Can you compare with yours?

Comment: Are you trying to access the service from the same machine it is hosted on?

Comment: In your bin/debug folder (or wherever you are running the EXE from), do you see an .exe.config file? This is the app.config that your app is loading. Open it in notepad and make sure the contents match your LIB's app.config. My guess is that it is attempting to load your host's app.config and not your lib's. I don't think VS auto merges them on build, and therefore your WCF information is missing. This is why I tend to stay away from defining info in a lib's (or any) app.config.

Comment: I don't have any app.config file content at all - I thought the point of a self-hosted WCF example was that it was all done in code, and the code fully defines everything required, and note that the full example halfway down the example page does say to create a class library and not a WCF Service Library.   Your library config file should be harmless though as I can't see how this gets loaded except under the WCF Service Host.  .Net Framework 3.5 by the way! - long story...

Comment: I would suggest creating a console app, adding a reference to System.ServiceModel, adding your code and the calculator interface and service code from the example page and seeing if this works - it does for me.